# how to get name of application in facelets app

Tags: java, logging, facelets, seam

problem I'm trying to solve:  differentiating applications inside our log manager.

I'm trying to find a reliable way to dig the application name out of a Seam application to use in a logging statement.  For example, if the app was http://company.us/bottles/, I want to get the string "bottles".

I've tried `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestServletPath()`

one horrible way:

```
    Map appProps = (HashMap)Contexts.getApplicationContext().get("org.jboss.seam.properties");
    String answer = appProps.get("org.jboss.seam.core.init.jndiPattern").toString();
    String answers[] = answer.split("/");
    applicationName = answers[0];
```

so, hopefully there is a better way than that

```
 <version.richfaces>3.3.1.GA</version.richfaces>
    <version.seam>2.2.2.Final</version.seam>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with:

```
    ServletContext ctx = ServletLifecycle.getServletContext();
    String appName = ctx.getContextPath().replace("/","");
```

which meets my needs.